# Sort list of IP addresses with subnet mask, removing duplicates

Tags: python, perl, sorting, ip-address

I have a txt file with these IP addresses and would like to sort them removing duplicate IP addresses, but retain the /subnets.

```
4.4.4.4/32
4.2.2.2/32
4.4.4.4/32
4.2.2.2/32
4.2.2.2/28
4.4.4.4/24
2.2.2.2/32
```

Eg: After sorting and removing duplicates, the above becomes

```
4.4.4.4/32
4.2.2.2/32
4.2.2.2/28
4.4.4.4/24
2.2.2.2/32
```

Any tips using awk or perl or python? I would also like to sort in ascending order.

Comment: Why is a simple `sort -u` inadequate?

Comment: Thanks. sort -u is fine, but i was looking for a python/perl script. Should have worded my question clearly..

Comment: What is your expected output? Did you mean eliminating duplicating IP, regardless of the /32, /28, ...?

Comment: @rootinflux You might want to edit your question since it specifically says "Any tips using sed, awk, sort or perl, python?"

Comment: Sorry guys, I have edited the question.

Comment: Re the updated question: As you were told, all you need is a basic lexical sort. What problem are you having? Please show us your work.

Comment: You should have an example like 22.3.4.5/32, because your current example is so limited that pure ASCII sort can cope.

Comment: The posted desired output is not sorted by any obvious criteria. What is your sorting criteria?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this just using `sort -ur`.

Edit: To do this in python, you can do the following:

```
with open('ipaddress.txt', 'r') as f:
    address = sorted(list(set(line for line in f)), reverse=True)
    for ad in address:
        print(ad)
```

Comment: +1 for command line solution, as in 'sort -ur ipaddress.txt >ipaddress_uniq.txt'

Answer (score 2):

Since the data appear to be extremely regular it's fairly easy to ensure correct sorting in Python by use of the *key* argument. This is used to create a "sort key" for each instance in the list to be sorted. People often use a lambda as a sort key function, but for completeness here we'll **def**ine something useful.

The duplicate removal is better done before the sort in Python. Since the list has to be sorted anyway, it doesn't matter that converting it into a set will result in an arbitrary ordering of the unique strings, the easy way to "uniquieify" list *l* if ordering doesn't matter in Python is

```
l = list(set(l))
```

Your test data is badly chosen, by the way, since it will sort correctly (just by accident) on a lexical sort. So you would be much better off including some examples with two- and three-digit components in the addresses so this isn't true any more. I demonstrate the non-working sort by way of explanation.

```
In [42]: data = """\
4.4.4.4/32
4.2.2.2/32
4.4.4.4/32
4.2.2.2/32
4.2.2.2/28
4.4.4.4/24
2.2.2.2/32
12.13.14.15/24
11.12.13.14/24""".splitlines()

In [43]: data.sort()

In [44]: data
Out[44]: 
['11.12.13.14/24',
 '12.13.14.15/24',
 '2.2.2.2/32',
 '4.2.2.2/28',
 '4.2.2.2/32',
 '4.2.2.2/32',
 '4.4.4.4/24',
 '4.4.4.4/32',
 '4.4.4.4/32']

In [45]: data = list(set(data))

In [46]: data.sort()

In [47]: data
Out[47]: 
['11.12.13.14/24',
 '12.13.14.15/24',
 '2.2.2.2/32',
 '4.2.2.2/28',
 '4.2.2.2/32',
 '4.4.4.4/24',
 '4.4.4.4/32']

In [48]: def sortkey(addr):
   ....:     add, pref = addr.split("/")
   ....:     a, b, c, d = (int(x) for x in add.split("."))
   ....:     return a, b, c, d, int(pref)
   ....: 

In [49]: data.sort(key=sortkey)

In [50]: data
Out[50]: 
['2.2.2.2/32',
 '4.2.2.2/28',
 '4.2.2.2/32',
 '4.4.4.4/24',
 '4.4.4.4/32',
 '11.12.13.14/24',
 '12.13.14.15/24']
```

It doesn't matter too much that the sort key function is in Python, since it is applied only once to each list value as a part of a "decorate/sort/undecorate" algorithm. More generally, for this problem domain you might find the ipaddress module helpful: http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/ipaddress.html

Answer (score 1):

in python you can do:

```
In [3]: l = []

In [4]: with open('ipaddress.txt', 'r') as input_file:
   ...:     for elem in input_file.readlines():
   ...:         if elem.strip() not in l:
   ...:             l.append(elem.strip())
   ...:

In [5]: l
Out[5]: ['4.4.4.4/32', '4.2.2.2/32', '4.2.2.2/28', '4.4.4.4/24', '2.2.2.2/32']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get unique lines in the order they appear in the file using awk:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

If you want the whole pipeline:

```
awk '/#/{sub(/#.*/,"",$0)} length($0) && !seen[$0]++' ipnum.txt
```

<sub>untested</sub>